# Add upload image button to the new mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

I'd like to see an "upload" button added to the new mobile chat (accepting both web links and local files).

It would make it so much more convenient to take pictures of my cats and repost them.

Comment: No such option as far as I can tell either, better change this into a feature request.

Comment: Workaround (not a solution).  Use the StackExchange app.  Ask a question (but don't post it). Include the picture you want. Grab the imgur link generated.  Copy and paste into chat. Delete the draft question.

Comment: @michaelt You can also switch temporarily to the desktop chat site and use the upload button there.

Comment: @JasonC you can... but that is a *painful* experience (at least for me - zoom - tap, wait, those buttons are too close, zoom, tap, dialog over there, zoom, tap, upload, go through hoops to get back to mobile).  Multiple app copy and paste is a bit easier of an experience. All that said, a 'image upload' that is appropriate is likely a better experience over either workaround.